# Getting error while running docker run :Error response from daemon

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04

Getting error while running docker command. I have successfully installed Docker in Google Cloud VM. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 image.

After installation when running docker run I am getting the below error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to start shim: exec: "docker-containerd-shim": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

Comment: Have a look at this. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1474724
Possible solution to this issue

Comment: @ValerianPereira solution provided in the link is to restart the docker service.  However, I feel this should be the last solution. I am in finding the root cause for the above issue. Unfortunetly, nothing shown in the logs. Could you elaborate it to reach the root cause?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me when I got this error:

> failed to start shim: exec: "docker-containerd-shim": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade
- sudo reboot 0
- sudo reboot 0
  (Yes, I had to reboot twice, a `*** System restart required ***` message was the clue.)

Then my Docker commands worked again.

Answer (score 2):

Restart the docker service using following command and It will start working.

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: I feel this should be the last solution. I am in finding the root cause for the above issue. Unfortunetly, nothing shown in the logs. Could you elaborate it to reach the root cause?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error:

*failed to start shim: exec: "docker-containerd-shim": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown*

Worked with the commands

```
1-systemctl restart docker
2-systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error.
I found that this error is related to the update/upgrade of docker.
It might happen that you have enabled automatic updates enabled(please disable it).

Btw it also works for me on restarting the docker.

you can also run this command:

```
systemctl restart docker
```