# Error response from daemon: failed to start shim: fork/exec /usr/bin/containerd-shim: too many open files: unknown

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using docker executor in Gitlab to build Ci/CD pipelines. And frequently I am facing this particular issue. It started happening all of a sudden and all the builds started breaking.

I did some googling and the only root cause I could find is people asking to restart Docker but that should not be the end solution.
[Getting error while running docker run :Error response from daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269687/getting-error-while-running-docker-run-error-response-from-daemon)

Error I am seeing -

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.6.0 (8fa89735)
  on docker-runner XBb4YMoN
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:12
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.systems.co.uk/devopstooling/dockerimages:node-14 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: adding cache volume: set volume permissions: running permission container "dkfhdfdsjkhdfjlk;jfl;ndbjkfbjkdsbfj" for volume "runner-xbb4ymon-project-50-concurrent-2-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70": starting permission container: Error response from daemon: failed to start shim: fork/exec /usr/bin/containerd-shim: too many open files: unknown (linux_set.go:105:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.systems.co.uk/devopstooling/dockerimages:node-14 ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: adding cache volume: set volume permissions: running permission container "jgfjdfkjdshufusdbksdbkjfbdjkbfjlsdnklfnsdklfnkls" for volume "runner-xbb4ymon-project-50-concurrent-2-cache-3c3f060a0374fc8bc39395164f415a70": starting permission container: Error response from daemon: failed to start shim: fork/exec /usr/bin/containerd-shim: too many open files: unknown (linux_set.go:105:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
```

Anyone has any idea what could be issue here and what can i do to fix this permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The source of it was that there was not enough space left on gitlab vm's disk (and on the VM that ran the runner).

Also check that is there enough RAM for gitlab and the runner.
I had too little RAM and storage space too, so I'm not sure which one caused the error.